# Audioconvert with Python & Gstreamer

Tags: python, gstreamer

I'm trying to use Gstreamer and Python.

I would like to have something like this in my pipeline :

```
audioconvert ! audio/x-raw,format=(string)S16LE,channels=(int)1,layout=(string)interleaved,rate=(int)48000 !
```

But I don't know how to add the caps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The caps in a launch line is actually converted into a `capsfilter` with the `caps` property set to the value of the caps.